# MySQL: statement prepared from text variable doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in MySQL that creates sql query for example this:

```
select
a.street,
a.bild,
a.korp,
a.flat,
a.serial_num,
nlog.value
from(  
    select 
    cli.street,
    cli.bild,
    cli.korp,
    cli.flat,
    dev.serial_num,
    mlog.value,
    max(mlog.id) as $max_id
    from mbus_clients as cli
    join mbus_devices as dev 
    on dev.id_client=cli.id
    join mbus_log as mlog
    on mlog.serial_num=dev.serial_num  
    where street like CONCAT($in_street,'%')
 AND bild=1 AND korp='t' AND flat=1
)as a
join mbus_log as nlog 
on a.$max_id = nlog.id;
```

this query works fine and stored in `$query` variable which has type: text(65535).
When I try `PREPARE stmnt1 FROM 'SELECT'` this works fine, but when I try `PREPARE stmnt1 FROM $query` mysql says about some mistake in syntax. What is the problem?

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `mbusGetClientsByStreet`;;
    CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'chl.rontel.ru' PROCEDURE `mbusGetClientsByStreet`(
        $in_street char(50),
        $in_amount int(11),
        $in_bild int(11),
        $in_korp char(1),
        $in_flat int(11)
        )
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        COMMENT ''
    begin
    /*Скопин C.С. 01.09.2014
    получение списка клиентов по части названия улицы и полного адреса*/
        declare $query text(65535);
        set $query ="
        select
        a.street,
        a.bild,
        a.korp,
        a.flat,
        a.serial_num,
        nlog.value
        from(  
            select 
            cli.street,
            cli.bild,
            cli.korp,
            cli.flat,
            dev.serial_num,
            mlog.value,
            max(mlog.id) as $max_id
            from mbus_clients as cli
            join mbus_devices as dev 
            on dev.id_client=cli.id
            join mbus_log as mlog
            on mlog.serial_num=dev.serial_num  
            where street like CONCAT($in_street,\'%\')
        ";
        if $in_bild is NOT NULL  THEN

        SET $query = CONCAT($query,' AND bild=',$in_bild);
            if $in_korp is NOT NULL THEN

                set $query = CONCAT($query,' AND korp=\'',$in_korp,'\'');

            end if;
            if $in_flat is NOT NULL THEN
                set $query = CONCAT($query,' AND flat=',$in_flat);
            end if;
        end if;
        set $query=CONCAT($query,'
        )as a
        join mbus_log as nlog 
        on a.$max_id = nlog.id;
        ');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM $query;
        SELECT $query;
    end;
```

Comment: Did you escape the quotes?

Comment: What does it say? can you post the error? Also try @query.

Comment: I've added text of procedure.  Well I escaped it. Is anything else wrong?

Comment: Why are your variables starting with ```$```? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: It is possible to start variables from $.

Comment: It says:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$query
end' at line 30
Not informative enough=(

Comment: Replaced $ before $query on @ and that works fine. Thanx, lol.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the variables do not have the values that you expect. For instance, if the variables are not defined, then you will have empty positions in your query.  Something like:

```
on a. = nlog.id;
```

And this would generate an error.

Or, you might have a value such as "max id" and have:

```
on a.max id = nlog.id
```

I would suggest that you explicitly put the values in the SQL string and then print out the string after variable substitution.  This should make the error clearer.